# Polymer- set modal true in paper-dialog

Tags: modal-dialog, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

*Polymer 1.0*

How do I render a `modal` in a `paper-dialog` element so the user must click a button to escape the modal and can not escape it by simply clicking on the background?

I tried `<paper-dialog modal></paper-dialog >` but there is no success...the user can still click on the background to close the modal.

I also tried `<paper-dialog modal="{ true }"></paper-dialog >` to no success.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's your use case? Why would you want a modal the user can not escape from? Or, for clarity, are you saying that your goal is to force the user to click a button to close the modal and not the background. Now that I think about it, that latter scenario seems like what you might want, but could you please confirm?

Comment: You are correct, I do not want the user to be able to click on the backdrop to close the modal. I want them to be forced to use the dismiss button.

Comment: Ah...haven't spent any time on it yet, but I suspect this can only be done with `paper-dialog-behavior`.

Comment: If you do figure out the answer, please fill out your answer below in the answer section for others to follow. This is a pretty useful thing to know and I would certainly love the chance to upvote any answer you provide yourself. Shows diligence, thoughtfulness and helpfulness to others.

Answer (score 1):

This is only available for `paper-dialog-behavior`. [Good examples here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-behavior/tree/master/demo)

Answer (score 0):

The first (`<paper-dialog modal></paper-dialog>`) should work.

Is your paper-dialog inside another element? The backdrop might not be positioned correctly if the dialog is inside an element that creates a new stacking context... More on this issue [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog/issues/7) (GitHub issue on paper-dialog).

From that you have two options: move the dialog to the top level or hack your way into getting the backdrop in the right place like @dhpollack in the issue above.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the user to be able to close the `<paper-dialog>` element by clicking anywhere outside the modal window, then you can add "no-cancel-on-outside-click" inside the `<paper-dialog>` tag.

Referenced from here:

https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/issues/405#issuecomment-287426314